Авторизация в Wi-Fi сети Mikrotik
Настроил hotspot в роутере Mikrotik, при подключении к сети Wi-Fi открывается страница авторизации. Шаблон авторизации я поменял, после ввода логина и пароля эти данные отправляются на другой сервис, реализованный мною. Не пойму только что делать после проверки корректности логина и пароля. Надо ли делать редирект или отдавать какой-нибудь ответ в другом формате?
